# app.config is ignored, but bin/debug/config.dll is not, on ADO VS TEST

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, azure-devops, automation

Running a VS Test on ADO, and I have .gitignore to ignore the config.dll file on bi/debug/... However this is not working.

```
            <add key="DriversPath" value="" />
```

app.config file has this

```
            <add key="DriversPath" value="C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\ChromeDriver" />
```

The app.config is ignored entirely. If the values were switched, where the config.dll has this value, and the app.config does not, it will state that a chromedriver.exe is missing.

.gitingore file states this;

```
Automation/Automation/bin/Debug/Automation.dll.config`
```

I have ran this on the MASTER branch also, then made a branch based of it to try, but did not work.

```
git rm -r . --cached
```

Anything else i could be doing to overcome this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The app.config belongs to an executable not to a dll.

Comment: So by using the config.dll, i am doing the right thing?

Comment: I don't know can't follow your problem beyond the fact that settings belong into a *.exe.config file that lives alongside the used starting process (the executable). Settings in a *.dll.config aren't used in the running process. Maybe its less confusing when you not talk about a config.dll while having a dll.config at the same time (when its presumably the same thing?).

Comment: I am running UI Tests on ADO for VS2019 EasyRepo Selenium. I have my app.config file, which shares the exact same values as my parallel Automation.dll.config. When i make changes to app.config for the chromedriver path, it does not recognise it, but when i have the path in Automation.dll.config, it recognises it. I am also referencing the Automation.dll from bin/debug for tests to run, which now assume is very wrong, and instead should be referenced from library folder?